# ASP.NET MVC3 Forms Authentication user logon session renew

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

I have an AJAX method to call on server to return ".ASPXAUTH" cookie expiration time.
It works properly when the auth cookie presents.

Besides I want to renew user logon session with another AJAX call. I have a blank method "RenewSession" which is just for to make a call to the server. Is there any way to do this using Forms Authentication?
The problem is in that when I make a request to server to my "RenewSession" method to renew the session Response.Cookies array is always containing 0 items. But actually when the ".ASPXAUTH" cookie expiration time gets to 0 it renews.

So can anyone explain is it a browsers' or ASP.NET/MVCs' behaviour? 
Maybe I need sliding expiration to be set to "true"?
Or maybe in my renew method I should re-login the user and put a new cookie in the response?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have slidingExpiration="false" in web.config? Because if not, the default is "true", and in your case it sounds like it's "true".

Comment: I have had no "slidingExpiration" attribute at all but by default it's being set to "false".

Comment: How is it "being set to false" by default, when you don't set it, and the default is "true"?

Comment: Actually I've made a lot of seaching and I've found that the only way to renew the session after a request is by using "slidingExpiration" set to "true" and only when half of the timeout period had passed.

And now I'm wondering how the process of session renewal happens when "slidingExpiration" is being set to "false"? MVC stores an indicator whether a request was done during the session period and if yes at the end of current session it renews it?

Comment: Nah, you can do it manually - see below. Sliding expiration uses the `RenewTicketIfOld` method i quote - on every request. If timeout is set to 20, it will add another 20 minutes if more than 10 minutes have passed since the last renewal.

Comment: As for "how does session renewal happen when 'slidingExpiration' is set to 'false'?", the answer is: It doesn't, unless you do it. It will expire [timeout] minutes after `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie`, no matter how many requests the user makes after that - unless you manually renew it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FormsAuthentication expiration is really a matter of two parts:

- the expiration of the authentication ticket
- the expiration of the cookie containing the ticket

If you want to leave sliding expiration off, and renew the ticket manually, you need to renew the ticket and return a new authentication cookie to the browser.

The `Response.Cookies` array is empty unless you (or other code) add something to it. It's only meant for adding cookies that are *new* or whose contents/expiration/whatever have *changed*. An empty `Response.Cookies` only means that nothing has changed - the browser will keep the cookies it already has (until they expire) and still send them on the next request.

The standard way of modifying cookie contents or expiration is to take a cookie the browser sent (from `Request.Cookies`), modify it, and then add it to `Response.Cookies`.

Here's a bit of sample code for manually renewing the authentication cookie (disclamer: Test thoroughly and think):

```
// You could also get the ticket from
// Request.Cookies using FormsAuthentication.Decode
FormsIdentity identity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as FormsIdentity;
if (identity == null) return; // User isn't authenticated

// Renew the ticket - you could also create a new ticket manually 
// (see * below for an example), if you want to get rid of ASP.NET's 
// rather confusing renew-if-old policy:
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = 
   FormsAuthentication.RenewTicketIfOld(identity.Ticket);

string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(
   FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
   encryptedTicket
);

// Better keep this (see * below):
cookie.Secure = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL;
cookie.HttpOnly = true;

// Isn't a security issue if this is set too long - the ticket contained
// within will still expire after the set time, and the server will timeout
// the auth session on the next request.
// But let's just keep cookie and ticket in sync:
cookie.Expire = ticket.Expiration;

// Add cookie to response to send the changes to the browser:
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Note that `FormsAuthentication.RenewTicketIfOld()` won't always renew the ticket. It will only renew if less than half of the expiration time is left. I.e., if your timeout in web.config is set to 20 minutes and RenewTicketIfOld is called 7 minutes after the ticket was created, the ticket won't be renewed, and there'll still be 13 minutes left. If it's called after e.g. 12 minutes, it will be renewed to 20 minutes.

The reason for this is because RenewTicketIfOld is used by slidingExpiration on every request and so would send back a new cookie on every request (to reset the expiration to [timeout] minutes). Only sending a new ticket cookie back when at least half the time has elapsed gets rid of a lot of cookie overhead - at the expense of being confusing to developers and end users.

*) On `cookie.Secure`, see Hanselman: [Weird Timeouts](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WeirdTimeoutsWithCustomASPNETFormsAuthentication.aspx) - this simply makes sure that if RequireSSL is set in web.config, the cookie will honor that, which avoids many a debugging nightmare if you ever move the site to SSL.